# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. > !zip.isFile()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-services

**@UPDATE**

Thank you very much. Now at least there are no errors. But it's still a far cry from how it worked before - how it should work. Now, the database looks ... strange. I think that something is still wrong with this gradle.

[image]

It should not look like. According to the java code in the database will be user and its data (name, email, date of account creation, id avatar) [image]

In the application at the site next to the avatar you should display the name. Unfortunately, as you can see nothing happens. There is nothing wrong with the code because it previously worked. :(

---

I ruined my project! I tried to fix it but now it's worse than it was.

The project is chat client through Firebase.

It started when I deleted my base. I had too many test users, messages I wanted to clear it. Since then, it gets a million error notifications - trying to fix one thing leads to even worse errors.

I tried to connect to the application completely different base, I tried to re-arrange a few things. Nothing helps.

At first I thought that the problem is with wrong compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0' number. Then I received

> E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.

I try to fix it. Application was started and in the database was very strange things.

Now i get

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.> !zip.isFile()

**build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}
```

**build.gradle (module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rachel.komunikator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0' 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Google Play Services** 
on my emulator

[image: version of Google Play Services on emulator]

Im using: Android Studio 2.2.3 and Nexus 5X Emulator

**@UPDATE**

> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found. E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API
>
> initialization failure. D/FirebaseApp:
>
> com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.

all logs:

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.rachel.komunikator-2/lib/x86

          [ 02-02 20:56:04.988  1566: 1589 D/         ]
          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8cf20100, tid 1589
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.rachel.komunikator, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.rachel.komunikator-2/lib/x86
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
               java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/data/com.example.rachel.komunikator/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-iid-9.0.0_8eee9db5e99a0da2dcdc7b52647c81db3aed29e6-classes.dex)
                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751) 
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726) 
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
               java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/data/com.example.rachel.komunikator/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-basement-9.8.0_b60271da061b8a83af31355011409573bfa72cef-classes.dex)
                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzbd(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751) 
                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726) 
                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: This seems to be a glitch in the Android Studio/Gradle integration. I find that selecting `Build > Rebuild Project` and then re-running usually fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Clean and Rebuild project should work. It work for me. Look at this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230211

Answer (score 11):

Regarding this:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.> !zip.isFile()

I solved it by deleting the `build` project and running again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked for me! make sure you delete the build folder inside the app folder

Answer (score 8):

Its very simple just run ./gradlew clean

If you are using Cordova or Ionic Framework run following commands

```
cd platforms/android
./gradlew clean
```

Its easy fix.

Answer (score 4):

I met this problems just A few minutes ago, I tried some ways in this question, but it's not work. So I asked other programmers for help, then it worked!

It's very easy! just do it as the figure shows below.

[image: First Step]

[image: Second Step]

I hope that would help you．

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15795308)

Comment: I so sorry for my poor English.But I think you guys can read and understand my options.That is most important !

Answer (score 4):

Just disable **Instant Run**:

```
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Instant Run
```

Answer (score 1):

Move this line to the BOTTOM of your `module:app` build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Example in the [Setup Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230211), try to use the new version of gradle : [2.3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

> This issue has been fixed in
>   ag/I6a6ef1a95732118b8e330b64fe4389710a3a2657. Please use newer gradle
>   plugin 2.3.0-beta2 or, if using 2.2.x, disable new packaging by using
>   the "android.useOldPackaging=true" flag.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the core firebase lib.

Add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'`

Comment: When I add this line I got error: 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> !zip.isFile()

Comment: Do a clean and re-build

Answer (score 0):

I solve this question.i just change my gradle version from 2.2.3 to 2.2.2
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I clicked the rebuild icon (its guide: "sync project with gradle file") and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I use Cordova CLI and have run into this issue from time-to-time.  Given that I build locally on my Windows 10 computer user permissions is not the issue.  I found that from time to time Cordova simply deletes the android/builds folder and then is for some reason unable to create it.  I simply recreate that folder manually and all is hunkry-dory.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you open another project simultaneously, it might give this issue. To overcome this issue you can:

```
flutter clean
```

After clean get your project packages through

```
flutter pub get
```

**For Android Studio Users:**

- You can easily navigate to file and clear invalid caches.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on root of the project ex:app select>>Show in Explorer and delete .gradle file and click on the clean OR Built option it will work 100%.